# How to set the fixed position for floating action button above very long listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, floating-action-button

I am developing an Android app that is mostly working with `listview`. But I am having a problem using `Floating Action Button` together with `Long ListView`. My problem is as below.

When the list view is only has a few item. `Floating item` can be seen.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see above, `Floating Action Button` is still can be seen.But when `ListView` has so many items and become excessive to the screen, `Floating Action Button` cannot been seen.

This is the screenshot of `Long Listview`

[image]

For the second screen shot, it cannot be `scrolled down` any more.

What I want to achieve is, I want the floating bottom always at the bottom right of screen above `Listview`. Like fixed position in `HTML` and `CSS`.

I want `Floating Action Button` always here no matter how tall the `Listview` is

[image]

This is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_item_divider_height"
            android:padding="@dimen/list_padding"
            android:divider="@color/whitesmoke"
            android:id="@+id/listview_podcast_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

        <TextView
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/tf_no_records"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/stop_podcast_button"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix my code to achieve it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. And for FloatingActionButton add attribute like this,

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
```

Comment: you are love bro :-*

Comment: Is `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` necessary? What would be the case when `LinearLayout`'s `ParentEnd` wouldn't match `ParentRight`

Answer (score 6):

Try using with **CoordinatorLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="listview.anubavam.com.listview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't place button in a Linear Layout .

Use

**FrameLayout** so you can place Views on top of others